# Aligning dominos onto any Curve with GN

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I'm trying to create a setup with GN to align dominos on any curve, that follows the direction AND the tilt of the shape.

So far, it works with simple shapes, but as soon as I try to add tilt to the curve, it fails.

This is the closest I could get, It kind of works, but if you look closely to the curve, you'll see that the dominos aren't grounded on the curve.

Another solution would be to instance the dominos on the mesh result of the curve, but I don't know how to tell GN to use the center face only, on the top side of the curve.

[image]

Here's the file if you want to take a look :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxfm10m0qumwqor/GN_curve.blend?dl=0

EDIT :

On this screenshot the problem is much more obvious. This is a bent spiral.

[image]

Comment: Do you want all yoour dominoes upright?

Comment: Well, yes. I'd like them to be perpendicular to the face of the ramp.

Comment: Well it is aligned to the normal of the faces of the ramp on your screenshots

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- If can you create the profile on the curve at the same time as the dominos, in the same GN tree, it would be easier to keep the top of the path-profile and the bottom of the dominos aligned.
- The *Curve to Points* node has a convenience 'Rotation' output, which can rotate the dominos to lie on the curve in one move.

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, it's so simple... I feel stupid to have not tried this.
It works very weel, now I can tumble the dominos easily.
The trick was to convert directly the curve to a mesh for the distribution.
Thank you very much !!!